# How to cast an array of UIViewControllers to an array of protocol types

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift, cocoa-touch, foundation

I have a `UITabBarController` whose `viewControllers` all implement the protocol `Refreshable`. How come I can't unwrap the tab bar controller's `viewControllers` property to an array of the `Refreshable` type?

```
if let tabs = self.tabBarController.viewControllers as? [Refreshable] {
    // Some code
    tabs[0].refresh() // refresh() is a function in Refreshable
}
```

There are no compile errors, but the code inside the `if let` closure never gets executed. How can I do this correctly?

*ADD:*

This works, but I don't like it--I feel like I should be able to express this as in above.

```
if let tabs = self.tabBarController.viewControllers as? [UIViewController] {
    if tabs[0] is Refreshable {
        (tabs[0] as! Refreshable).refresh()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you just log `self.tabBarController.viewControllers`, I suspect it consist of `UINavigationController` rather than `UIViewController`, you might need to do two loops instead.

Comment: Ah, nope. The tab bar controller does directly contain the view controllers--no navigation controllers in between. In fact, if I test whether each tab `is Refreshable`, the code executes (see incoming question update).

Comment: Ah, you have got answer though, that looks correct to me.

Comment: Did you try forcing the type casting with `as! [Refreshable]`

Comment: Well if the `?` cast fails, a `!` would only cause a crash.

Comment: Exactly.. because, since the array is defined as a collection of `AnyObject`s, it is possible for you to add an object to this array which does not conform to `Refreshable` protocol and hence the `[Refreshable]` type checking for the entire `viewControllers` array will not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your array is `[UIViewController]`, it won't accept items with the type `Refreshable`, since other, arbitrary classes might conform to it, which do not have the properties of `UIViewController`.

In other words, `Refreshable` alone is not a strong enough promise for your array, since it won't guarantee `UIViewController` instances.

The original expression would only work on an array, where the type is specified by the protocol type like so:

```
// Suppose MyClass conforms to Refreshable

let myArray: [Refreshable] = [
    MyClass(),
    MyClass(),
    MyClass(),
    MyClass(),
]

// Now you can use refresh() without problems

for item in myArray {
    item.refresh()
}
```

Unfortunately, since you're using the property on a tab bar controller, I'm afraid this is not an option for you. A possible way to make sure you only use instances, which conform to `Refreshable` is to filter/map your array first like so:

```
let items = myarray.filter({ $0 is Refreshable }).map({ return $0 as! Refreshable })

// items will be [Refreshable]
for item in items  {
    item.refresh()
}
```

It is important to note here, that if you use the since `items` will be of type `[Refreshable]`, you can no longer assume it has properties from its original class (i.e. `MyClass`), only the ones the protocol grants them (i.e. `refresh()` in this case).

Answer (score 2):

the `viewControllers` property in the tab bar controller is declared as `[AnyObject]?` .. so the type check `as? [Refreshable]` does not go through.
instead, iterate through the view controllers and check type for each of them:

```
for viewController in self.tabBarController!.viewControllers! {
    if let refreshableTab = viewController as? Refreshable {
        refreshableTab.refresh()
    }
}
```

Comment: I find this strange even when my `Refreshable` protocol extends `AnyObject`. Anyway, have an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping up @József Vesza great answer, you can do something like:

```
if  let tabs = self.tabBarController.viewControllers as? [UIViewController],
    let refreshables = tabs.filter({ $0 is Refreshable }).map({ $0 as! Refreshable } {
        refreshables[0].refresh()
}
```